# Authentication Steps to BigQuery via Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, google-api, google-bigquery

I've created a project in Big Query and within API Access pane, I've created Service Account so that i can make Big Query API accessible through windows application on behalf of user interaction.  Since i am new to using and accessing Google API, I want to know the basic steps so that i can access Big Query via Windows Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some .NET code samples here using web-based OAuth flows:
[Google BigQuery with .NET documentation/ samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443878/google-bigquery-with-net-documentation-samples)

For an example from another dev using service accounts in .NET, see this:
[Google OAuth2 Service Account Access Token Request gives 'Invalid Request' Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939026/google-oauth2-service-account-access-token-request-gives-invalid-request-respo)

These manually implement service accounts on top of the .NET library.  The .NET library has recently added native support for service accounts, though I haven't yet found an official example.

Here's an unofficial sample working with the Analytics API.  It should be directly analogous to using service accounts with BigQuery:
[How do I use a Service Account to Access the Google Analytics API V3 with .NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980215/how-do-i-use-a-service-account-to-access-the-google-analytics-api-v3-with-net-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm able to generate a valid access token, but now the problem is, how to pass this access token to Big Query Service Object, so that i can communicate with Big Query API. I tried from my side as well as i searched most of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Finally here's the working code for Authentication process to Big Query API and retrieving records from Big Query table:-

I've created a class having a method of return type `OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>`.

```
 internal class clsGetOAuth2Authentication
    {
        public OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> objGetOAuth2(string strPrivateFilePath, string strPrivateFilePassword, string strServiceAccEmailId,string strScope)
        {
            AuthorizationServerDescription objAuthServerDesc;
            X509Certificate2 objKey;
            AssertionFlowClient objClient;
            OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> objAuth = null;

            string ScopeUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/" + strScope;
            string strSrvAccEmailId = strServiceAccEmailId; 
            string strKeyFile = strPrivateFilePath; //KeyFile: This is the physical path to the key file you downloaded when you created your Service Account.
            string strKeyPassword = (strPrivateFilePassword != "") ? strPrivateFilePassword : "notasecret"; //key_pass: This is probably the password for all key files, but if you're given a different one, use that.

            objAuthServerDesc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description; //objAuthServerDesc: Description of the server that will grant Authentiation. 
            objKey = new X509Certificate2(strKeyFile, strKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); //objkey: Load up and decrypt the key.
            objClient = new AssertionFlowClient(objAuthServerDesc, objKey) { ServiceAccountId = strSrvAccEmailId, Scope = ScopeUrl }; //objClient: Using the AssertionFlowClient, because we're logging in with our certificate.
            objAuth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(objClient, AssertionFlowClient.GetState); //objAuth: Requesting Authentication.
            return objAuth;
        }
    }
```

Now, another class calls the above method:-

```
clsGetOAuth2Authentication objOAuth2 = new clsGetOAuth2Authentication();
            try
            {
                var objAuth = objOAuth2.objGetOAuth2(strKeyFile, strKeyPassword, strSrvAccEmailId, strScope); //Authentication data returned
                objBQServ = new BigqueryService(objAuth); //Instantiate BigQueryService  with credentials(objAuth) as its parameter

                #region Retrieving Records:-
                JobsResource j = objBQServ.Jobs;
                QueryRequest qr = new QueryRequest();
                qr.Query = strQuery;

                DateTime dtmBegin = DateTime.UtcNow;
                QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, strProjId).Fetch();
                DateTime dtmEnd = DateTime.UtcNow;
                string strColHead = "";
                foreach (var colHeaders in response.Schema.Fields)
                {
                    strColHead += colHeaders.Name.ToString() + "\t";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(strColHead);
                int intCount = 0;
                foreach (TableRow row in response.Rows)
                {
                    intCount += 1;
                    List<string> list = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var field in row.F)
                    {
                        list.Add(field.V);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", list));
                }
                TimeSpan tsElapsed = dtmEnd - dtmBegin;
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Total no. of records:- " + intCount + ". Time taken:- " + tsElapsed);
                #endregion


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occured!" + "\n\n" + "Statement:- " + ex.Message.ToString() + "\n\n" + "Description:- " + ex.ToString() + "\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```