# SSL broken after modifying permissions on “Machine Keys” folder - Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error

Tags: ssl, iis-6, windows-server-2003, x509certificate

I have an ASP.NET web app running on my STAGE server (Windows 2003 server with IIS 6).

I've started using [Google Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) in my application, and it worked great on my DEV box (Windows 7 / IIS 7.5)

As I moved my code to STAGE server, I started getting ["The system cannot find the file specified" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14263457/3661); the solution was to load the user profile with the App Pool identity, but IIS 6 does not have that feature.

I've found a work-around for IIS 6, which was to give the App Pool account Read/Write permissions on

```
C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machine Keys
```

When I set the permissions, I've applied them to all child entities (via Advanced option); not only this didn't fix the error; but it also broke the SSL connection to my site.

I get `Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.`; non-SSL url works just fine.

My question is how to restore the proper permissions on `C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machine Keys` and fix my SSL connection?

Any other suggestions on fixing my SSL connection would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gave up on fixing the issue, since I was moving the application to a different server anyways; and it didn't look like any other applications were affected.

Then I restarted IIS, and all hell broke loose.

IIS was not starting back up; `IIS Admin Service` was not starting with "Error 6: Handle is invalid".

That error helped me to get to the bottom of the issue, and find the correct permissions on the `MachineKeys` folder.

[This article](http://sharepoint-geek.com/2010/05/05/iis-admin-error-handle-is-invalid-permissions-ssl-certificate-machinekeys/) pointed me to [Default permissions for the MachineKeys folders - KB 278381](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;278381) which had the correct permissions.

**NOTE:** KB article states that `Everyone` should have `Special Permissions` on `This folder only`; yet sharepoint-geek's article suggests applying those permissions to `This folder, subfolders, and files` (which I did).

Once the permissions were fixed, `iisreset` worked and even my SSL issue was resolved.

Hope this saves somebody hours of frustration.