# Trying to connect to Google Analytics API through .NET gives "400 Bad Request"

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-analytics-api

I am trying to connect to the Google Analytics API from a .NET application. Here is the code I've come up with:

```
Public Function GetData() As String   
    Dim client As AssertionFlowClient = New AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description,
                                                                New X509Certificate2("C:\Users\xxxxx\privatekey.p12", "notasecret",
                                                                                     X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable Or X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)) With {
                                                                .Scope = "analytics.readonly",
                                                                .ServiceAccountId = "xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com"}
    Dim authenticator As OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient) = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient)(client, AddressOf AssertionFlowClient.GetState)
    Dim service As AnalyticsService = New AnalyticsService(authenticator)

    Dim profileId As String = "ga:xxxxx"
    Dim startDate As String = "2013-02-15"
    Dim endDate As String = "2013-02-20"
    Dim metrics As String = "ga:visitors"

    Dim request As DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest = service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics)
    Dim data As GaData = request.Fetch()

    Return data.ToString()
End Function
```

My problem is that when I hit this method, I get an exception on the `request.Fetch()` line that says "Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response." The inner exception says, "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

This error is obviously pretty vague. According to [Google's documentation of the error codes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors), 400 Bad Request indicates that the input parameters don't make sense somehow. Can anyone diagnose the problem by looking at the parameters in my code? Otherwise, how would I even begin to track down what I'm doing wrong? There's virtually no information presented in the error.

(At least I've gotten past the authentication stage... I *think*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing extensively from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013265/371228), the solution I came up with is this:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports Google.Apis.Analytics.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class GoogleAnalytics

    Private _profileId As String
    Private _service As AnalyticsService

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates an instance of the Google Analytics interface
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="profileId">The Google Analytics profile ID, in the form "ga:123456789". This is *not* the same as the ID number used in the GA JavaScript to initialize the tracking! The number you want is in Google Analytics > Admin > (your profile) > Profile Settings.</param>
    ''' <param name="serviceAccountId">The e-mail address of the Service Account that will access the API. These accounts can be generated from the Google API Console and then authorized by adding the e-mail address to the list of authorized users in Google Analytics.</param>
    ''' <param name="privateKeyPath">The path to the private-key (.p12) file from Google.</param>
    ''' <param name="certificatePassword">The password for the private key. Probably "notasecret".</param>
    ''' <remarks>Once created, this GoogleAnalytics object can be used to make an arbitrary number of requests.</remarks>
    Public Sub New(profileId As String, serviceAccountId As String, privateKeyPath As String, certificatePassword As String)
        Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(privateKeyPath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable Or X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
        Dim client As AssertionFlowClient = New AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, cert) With {.Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
                                                                                                                        .ServiceAccountId = serviceAccountId}
        Dim authenticator As OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient) = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient)(client, AddressOf AssertionFlowClient.GetState)
        _service = New AnalyticsService(authenticator)

        _profileId = profileId
    End Sub

    Public Function GetData(startDate As String, endDate As String, metrics As String, dimensions As String, Optional filters As String = Nothing) As GaData
        Dim request As DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest = _service.Data.Ga.Get(_profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics)
        request.Dimensions = dimensions

        If filters IsNot Nothing Then
            request.Filters = filters
        End If

        Return request.Fetch()
    End Function

End Class
```

This is a standalone class that can be used as follows:

```
Dim analytics As New GoogleAnalytics("ga:12345678", "123456789012@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "C:\privatekey.p12", "notasecret")
Dim data as GaData = analytics.GetData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                       DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                       "ga:totalEvents",
                                       "ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction")
```

The biggest gotcha I found with this was the Profile ID. This is *not* the ID number that you pass to Google's Javascript tracking code; instead, it's a number that you find in Google Analytics > Admin > (your profile) > Profile Settings. Hope this helps someone else!