# Oauth 2 to use with Google Analytics in .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I know the .net library for Google API is still in beta. But I need to use it because I find the Java tutorial very confusing. Easier to work in .net for me.

I need some helping code to do an OAuth2.0 authorization and then use Google Analytics API on a console application in C#.

I [have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684108/invalid-response-error-when-retrieving-google-analytics-data-with-a-service-acco) a post on this but unfortunately I get errors with it and it does not help. Does anyone know of a good source for that. There is not much documentation on this topic.

Comment: Here is my example: [1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429392/automated-use-of-google-api-dotnet-client-with-oauth-2-0/12603329#12603329

Comment: This might help http://ibanalytics.blogspot.dk/2013/09/google-oath2-installed-application.html   You will still have to pop open a browser for the user to atenticate it from a console app.   I have an example of it some place i think it was just something like start process with the URL would open the webbrowser.   then you can read from it the same as if it was a webbrowser component.