# Google Analytics API v3 / C# - System.Net.Http.Primitives Error

Tags: c#, api, google-analytics

After having trouble getting any of Google's samples to work I tried using the info here to test using the Analytics API:

[How do I use a Service Account to Access the Google Analytics API V3 with .NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980215/how-do-i-use-a-service-account-to-access-the-google-analytics-api-v3-with-net-c/13013265#13013265)

The first unexpected issue was that I had to switch my project from .NET 4.0 to 4.5 in order for the compiler to accept the Google.Api.* namespaces.  I would have preferred to stay with 4.0 but maybe that is a stated requirement that I missed?

My main issue though is that when I try to create a new AnalyticsService object I get: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0...'"  I saw one or two similar complaints but the only suggestion I found was to use the API's NuGet package, which didn't help.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on the [build](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Build#Using_NuGet) page for the .NET api (copied here as per community suggestions):

1. Install the specific Google API you want to use (e.g. [Google.Apis.Calendar.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3))
2. Install Google.Apis.Authentication