# Display Google Analytics data on my web site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, nopcommerce

I'm trying to figure out a way to display data collected from Google Analytics on my web site. I'm using NopCommerce, and I want to display this information/statistics in a view in the Admin Section.

There might be many ways to achieve this, and after searching the web I found some examples using JavaScript, but I couldn't find a good tutorial for this.

I have also looked into integrating Google Analytics with C#, and I found this example: http://biasecurities.com/2012/02/using-the-google-analytics-api-with-asp-net-mvc/#comment-1310
A demo project can be downloaded from GitHub here: https://github.com/jgeurts/Analytics-Example

However the demo project doesn't seem to work as the google URL (https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default) is no longer in use.

As I'm using a MVC application it would be preferable to make this happen by applying the Google Analytics logic within a Controller and displaying it in a view. Or something like that.

Google provides a query tool to experiment with here, so it shouldn't be to hard extracting data from Google Analytics and display the data on the website: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Has anyone been able to successfully display Google Analytics data on their website?

Comment: Thank you! 'll check that out

Comment: Got some namespace errors. Kinda unclear how to add GooglChartSharp to the project, got all kinds of errors with that

Comment: You can use GoogleAnalyticsAPI. It is free of cost and easy to integrate.

Comment: Yes i know but how? A working sampe would be preferable..

Comment: I have a tutorial on it but didn't published yet. I will publish and send link to you this evening.

Comment: @Kuzgun - Follow this link here and check out 3rd post, i did a short tutorial on how to implement a google analytics client in .NET/MVC. I think this will get you started. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855107/display-google-analytics-data-on-my-web-site/22089630#22089630

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case some one else is having the same problem here's what I did and it pretty much answers the question.

**1.**

Here is the basic code for a API client that access data from Google Analytics via your Google Service Account. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account

In order to make this application work you need to have several things ready before you start coding.

***Google Analytics Account** - once registered a "tracker" code is generated for you to put on each webpage you want to track. You may not see any statistics right away and it can take up to 24h before any statistics are shown in the Google Analytics Dashboard.

An OAuth Authorisation (API-Key) with CLIENT_ID, CLIENT SECRET and EMAIL ADRESS (This is not your normal email but a service account email that is created for you when you make an OAuth Authorisation).
console.developers.google.com/

A serverkey, can also be created here: console.developers.google.com/.
You can also create a browser key, haven't bothered with that though and don't know what it does.

Finally you need a certificate key. Your application will only be able to access your Google Analytics account by using the key and credentials. The key is an encrypted p.12 file. You can find the key in  https://code.google.com/apis/console/.

Here is a guide for the key: http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Setup+Google+Analytics+Reporting+with+OAuth2+Service+Accounts+(since+1.4.6)

**2.**

Now that you have all keys and credentials you need it is time to start looking at the code I linked in "1". Here is the basic for it again: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account

Create a console application and implement the code above.

Note: your not making a "Google Plus service" so you have to change those parts for "AnalyticsService". Go to manage nuget and install packages:

- Google Apis Core Library
- Google Apis Client Library
- Google Apis Auth Client Library
- Google Apis Analytics.v3 Library
- Google GData Client (This provides properties used to query data, metrics, demensions etc)
- Google GData Extensions Library
- Analytics

Might forgot something but here are the namespaces I use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3;
```

**3**

Finally, here's is some of my code. Note I'm creating a new Analytics as supposed to "new ServiceAccountCredentials" as in the code from Google. That's the main difference:
[Retrieve data from Google Analytics API with .NET, multiple metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041070/retrieve-data-from-google-analytics-api-with-net-multiple-metrics)

With this I'm able to access and query data from Google Analytics account. The best part is that you don't have to log in to Google for this as the key and credentials gives you access to the account data directly.

I will migrate this code to MVC now I might make an update later on for how to implement this Analytics client in Mvc.

Comment: Do you have a blog post on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 5):

This document explains how to get Google Access tokens and use them to get Google Analytics data to be displayed in our websites.

**Example:** A live example is available in

> https://newtonjoshua.com

Note: Use the same Gmail account for all the below steps.

---

### STEP 1: Set Up Google Analytics

Follow the below steps to set up Google Analytics on your website

1. Sign in to your Analytics account.
2. Select the Admin tab.
3. Select an account from the drop-down menu in the ACCOUNT column.
4. Select a property from the drop-down menu in the PROPERTY column.
5. Under PROPERTY, click Tracking Info -> Tracking Code.
6. To collect data, you must copy and paste the Analytics tracking code
   into the source code on every web page you wish to track.
7. Once you have the JavaScript tracking code snippet for your
   property, copy the snippet exactly without editing it.
8. Paste your tracking code snippet (unaltered, in its entirety) before
   the closing </head> tag on every web page on your site you wish to
   track.
9. Once you have successfully installed Analytics tracking, it may take
   up to 24 hours for data such as traffic referral information, user
   characteristics, and browsing information to appear in your reports

Refer to:

1. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en
2. https://analytics.google.com

---

### STEP 2: Get Tokens

**Google Project:**

To create a Google Cloud Platform project, open the Google Developers Console (https://console.developers.google.com) and click *Create Project.*

**Enable OAuth 2.0 API access:**

Your application will need to access user data and contact other Google services on your behalf. Use OAuth 2.0 to grant your app API access.

To enable that, you need a client ID:

1. Open the Google API Console Credentials page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).
2. From the project, drop-down and select your project.
3. Select *Create credential*s and choose *OAuth client ID*.
4. Under Application type, select *Web application*, enter a Name and
5. set the Restrictions by entering *JavaScript origins*, ***Redirect URIs*** to point the website where you are planning to display the data, and then click *Create*.
6. Make note of the OAuth 2.0 ***client_id*** and ***client_secret***. You will need them to configure the UI.

**Get Authorization code:**

Enter in browser:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code&client_id={{
>   client_id}}&redirect_uri={{redirect_uri }}
>   &approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline

You will get redirected to

> {{redirect_uri }}?code=={{***authorization_code***}}#

**Get Refresh Token:**

Send a POST request, possibly via a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) console to

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?code={{authorization_code}}
>   &client_id=*{{client_id}}*&client_secret=*{{client_secret}}*
>   &redirect_uri=*{{redirect_uri }}*&grant_type=authorization_code

You will get a JSON response with

> {"refresh_token": ***refresh_token***}

You can use the refresh token to get access token to access to Google APIs.

**Get the Access Token:**

Send a POST request to,

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?client_id=*{{client_id}}*
>   &client_secret=*{{client_id}}*
>   &grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=*{{refresh_token}}*

You will get a JSON with access_token in the response.

> {access_token: ***{{access_token}}***}

*Example:*

```
var access_token = '';
function getAccessToken(){
    $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', {
            client_id: {{client_id}},
            client_secret: {{client_secret}},
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: {{refresh_token}}
        }, function (data, status) {
            if (status === 'success') {
                access_token = data.access_token;
                // Do something eith the access_token
            }
            else {
                console.error(status);
            }
        });
}
```

**Check Token validity:**

Send a POST request to,

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={{access_token}}

*Example:*

```
function checkValidity() {
    $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo', {
            access_token:{{access_token}}
        }).done(function (data, status) {
            if (status === 'success') {
                console.debug(data.expires_in);
                var check = false;
                check = data.hasOwnProperty('expires_in');
                if (check) {
                    // Token is valid
                }
                if (!check) {
                    getAccessToken();
                }
            }
            else {
                console.debug(status);
            }

        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            console.error(data);
            getAccessToken();
        });
}
```

---

### Step 3: Fetch Data

**Embed API:**

The GA Embed API is a JavaScript library that allows you to easily create and embed your GA dashboard on your website in a matter of minutes.

Refer to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started.

**Query Explorer:**

Visit Embed API Query Explorer and authorize

> https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Select the view for which you want to fetch the data.

Select the required metrics and dimensions.

*Example:*

Get Country Data (I want to know the number of users accessing my website from each country).

To get that data, select the metrics as 'users' and the dimensions as 'country'.

Click on *Run Query*.

You will find the analytics data for the query displayed in a table.

Copy the ***API Query URI***. And add access_token=*{{access_token}}* to the URI.

*Example:*

> https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids={{ids}}&start-date=2015-07-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3A*country*&access_token=*{{access_token}}*

Send POST request to the URIs to get the data in your browser.

*Example:*

```
function gaGetCountry() {
    $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?' +
        'ids={{ids}}' +
        'start-date=2015-07-01&' +
        'end-date=today&' +
        'metrics=ga%3Ausers&' +
        'dimensions=ga%3Acountry&' +
        'sort=ga%3Ausers&' +
        'filters=ga%3Ausers%3E10&' +
        'max-results=50' +
        '&access_token=' + {{access_token}},
        function (data, status) {
            if (status === 'success') {

                // Display the Data
                drawRegionsMap(data.rows);

            } else {
                console.debug(status);
            }

        });
}
```

---

### Step 4: Display Data

Now we have gathered the data. Finally we have to display them on our website.

"*Display live data on your site*" is the title of Google Charts. And that is what we are going to do.

Refer to https://developers.google.com/chart/.

The following example will draw a [GeoChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) in the div with id='countryChart'.

```
// Draw country chart
function drawRegionsMap(data) {

    var head = data[0];
    head[0] = 'Country';
    head[1] = 'Users';
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var d = data[i];
        d[1] = Number(d[1]);
    }

    var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
    var options = {
        title: 'My Website is viewed from,',
        domain: '{{Country Code eg: IN for India}}',
        tooltip: {
            textStyle: {
                color: 'navy'
            },
            showColorCode: true
        },
        legend: {
            textStyle: {
                color: 'navy',
                fontSize: 12
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {
            colors: ['#00FFFF', '#0000FF']
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('countryChart'));

    chart.draw(chartData, options);
}
```

Refer to https://newtonjoshua.com to view the above example in action.

Comment: Included more details as requested.

Comment: I've deleted 20 documentation-link-only answers from you. Please don't spam our site with copy-and-paste answers, especially not *redundant* posts.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend to use the new [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) (currently in beta). Information about the [Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3) can be found here. Note that the Client Library for .NET (google-api-dotnet-client) supersedes the .NET library for the Google Data API (google-gdata).

Unfortunately, there is no sample code available yet from Google (see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=213&q=Component%3DSamples&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)) but [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980215/how-do-i-use-a-service-account-to-access-the-google-analytics-api-v3-with-net-c/13013265#13013265) should help.

If you don't want to login every time you access Analytics data, you can use OAuth 2.0 authorization with [offline access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline). You have to grant initial access to your web application, though. This requires you to login once but you can use a refresh token later on.

Comment: Found a good solution for logging in, im extracting data directly from the GA account instead of being forced to logg in. Works great and provides the data without unessesary authorisation issues. I followed this guide and switched PlusService to AnalyticsService : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account

Answer (score 2):

To date, the easiest solution is to create a report of your Google Analytics data in Google Data Studio (free, native connector to GA), and share that report to embed in an `<iframe>`

See details on https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en

You get

- flexible vizualisation
- security and control on the data being shared
- 0 code nor maintenance
- result is being cached for better performance

Answer (score 1):

1. Login with gmail account and open site of google analytics
2. Create your analytics account for your project with stepwise details provided by google.
3. After that  code give by them which will look like as follows

   ```
   <script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
     gtag('js', new Date());

     gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
   </script>
   ```

Add above code in every pages of your website.

4. After 7 hours you will be able see your report on google analytics site
5. Open Looker studio,where you can create template using drag drop facility. url : https://lookerstudio.google.com/navigation/reporting
   steps given in tutorila report to design template.
6. After that embed in  in your website page that templte will be visible in your website and you can see realtime data on your site
7. Which is flexible and secure solution.