# Retrieve data from Google Analytics API with .NET, multiple metrics?

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I'm writing this Console Application to get some basic "Google Analytics Api-data" logic going. Everythings works fine but i wan't to add some more metrics to query to google analytics API. I wan't to add ga:newvisitors, ga:reaccuringvisitors etc. How do i implement this in the code below?

Here's a relevant piece of the code:

```
var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
       HttpClientInitializer = credential,
       ApplicationName = "TestGoogleAnalytics",
       });

var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:ProfileID", "2010-02-24", "2014-02-24", "ga:visitors");

//Specify some addition query parameters
r.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
r.Sort = "-ga:visitors";
r.MaxResults = 10000;

//Execute and fetch the results of our query
Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = r.Execute();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in d.TotalsForAllResults)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Total Visitors:" +" " + kvp.Value);
    }

Console.WriteLine(d.TotalsForAllResults.Keys + " = " + d.TotalsForAllResults.Values);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metrics are the last item in the get request just separate them with a comma.

```
var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:ProfileID", "2010-02-24", "2014-02-24", "ga:visitors,ga:newvisitors,ga:reaccuringvisitors");
```

Might be easer to read this way:

```
string Metrics = "ga:visitors,ga:newvisitors,ga:reaccuringvisitors";
var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:ProfileID", "2010-02-24", "2014-02-24", Metrics);
```

make sure you have the names right those don't look right to me but I didn't check:  [Dimension and metric reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) .

Update:  [ga:newvisitors](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/PWsn6Jw_9P4) was removed back in 2009. I cant find any reference to ga:reaccuringvisitors. Make sure your requesting the correct metrics.

Comment: Hmm alright, i did something similar but formated the code the wrong way i guess. Thanks i'll try this =)

Comment: Oh i didn't know they removed it, i need some more statistics to draw a chart. Reacurringvisitors dosn't excist but i think ga:percentNewVisits can be used.  However i get this error when runing the code, the error accurs when i execute "r" like this  Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = r.Execute();  The error says -  "Parameter validation failed for "ids"

Comment: ga:ProfileID is the Id of the profile in GA that you want to access.  Go to Admin of the view its under View Settings - View Id its a number  you have to put ga: in fount of it (ga:78110423)

Comment: It works now thank you! I got the id-problem when using the "string metrics" variant but the other alternative you provided works. I now get Total visitors and PercentNewVisits =)