# Site Stats for nopCommerce plugin

Tags: c#, wordpress, nopcommerce

My current website is developed using Wordpress. One great plugin of this platform is the Jetpack plugin, which lists the site stats such as:

- Views per day
- number of views on each blog post or product
- where people reach your site from, such as: google search, Facebook, etc.
- a graph to visualize the difference of views between each day
- number of view base on country, example: 3 views from Vietnam and 2 views from the US

And many more that I can list them here.

Now, I want to move my site to another platform, which is NopCommerce, since I am not familiar with php so that it is really hard for me to customize the website.

I wonder that is there any nopcommerce plugin that does the similar things as Jetpack plugin in Wordpress?

Comment: How about an Google Analytics integration? There is a out-of-the-box plugin for this.

Comment: This could be of interest for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21855107/3351148