# Google Big Query with C# Server to Server

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, server-to-server

I', using

Google .NET Client Library

Stable Release '1.6.0-beta' (Wednesday, October 23, 2013)

But the samples it contains, any one refers to bigquery.

the examples I found, refer to the Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.dll which I found somewhere else
and other dlls, that are not in the client library... I have them all already! But I still cant
make the sample work!...

both examples in this question

[Google BigQuery with .NET documentation/ samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443878/google-bigquery-with-net-documentation-samples)

have methods that are not valid now. like "Fetch", or some classes not compatible or different!

¿Can any of you, share me a small project, just to make a query to a table?

I already have the table on the paid service, I can query it from the webpage!... I just need to do it from a c# simple console connecting server to server, in order to start using it in my web application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have C# to test it, but I have some pointers:

- You can find the latest BigQuery dll at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/bigquery/v2.
- For an example that uses OAuth2, follow https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted

Once you are done installing the dlls and OAuth2 it should be easy to run and review the BigQuery code, even if I can't run it.

Comment: I already have the nugget bigquery dll, and I also already connect to the oauth2 using the browser!... what I cant do is the server to server authentication and send a query to the table. Have you done it with any other language? can you post the code? maybe I can get some ideas

Comment: https://github.com/lordfist/FistCore.Lib/blob/master/FistCore.Extend.BigQuery/Connector/JWTGoogleAuth.cs , it uses old client though but still works normally