# code using simba bigquery visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, google-bigquery

currently im querying gbq through odbc, was working alright until a few days ago it started giving me a timeout poll error, doesnt matter if the results it is going to throw are small or big. I started looking around for a fix and decided to use the gbq connector using google.cloud.bigquery.v2.3.2.0, found samples to use it but theyre all in different languages and cant seem to port it to visual basic. Does anyone have a working sample on how to connect to gbq through this library or any suggestion to point me in the correct direction? currently my connection strings are like this:

```
 Dim BQConnectionString As String = "Driver=Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery;OauthMechanism=1;Email=" & GoogleMAIL & ";Catalog=" & BQCATALOG & ";RefreshToken=" & BQTOKEN

            BQConnection = New ADODB.Connection
            BQConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 0
            BQConnection.CommandTimeout = 0
            BQConnection.Open(BQConnectionString)
            BQRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
            With BQRecordset
                .Open(Query, BQConnection)
            End With
```

would need something like this but using the mentioned connector and my simba configuration, part to log in and to use my query, thanks a lot in advance

tried using this code as reference but converting it to vb didnt work, expected to log in succesfully to use gbq and retrieve data with a query

[How to integrate Google Bigquery with c# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819153/how-to-integrate-google-bigquery-with-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: You've said it isn't working, but you've not really explained exactly how it's not working then linked an article that is using a webservice rather than odbc to connect, again saying you couldn't get it to work with no explanation of what didn't work.  Perhaps you might want to re-phrase your question to what exactly you want examples/solutions for?  The linked article looks like C#, may code converters around that will convert it pretty well and may only require minor changed.

Comment: Converted to VB? From what?

Comment: thanks a lot, I apologize for my ignorance, when I say it stopped working it means that previously it would run the query and return results no problem, now it runs the query but it just returns the error {"[Simba][BigQuery] (115) Operation timeout. PollJob"} , dont want to use a webservice I would like to use vb and bigquery connector but havent found anything related to it, if someone has any link or something Id appreciate it a lot.